# how to make a public server in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, server, ip

why the code works on local ip but not on public ip?
I already tried to set a permanent address but still nothing, only when I gave a local IP address it worked. It seems to me that it may be a problem with the code because, after a moment of thinking, python shows an error
Of course I've done things like setting up port forwarding, DMZ, firewall on the router.

```
import socket, requests

def get_public_ip():
    response = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org')
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.text
    else:
        return None
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = (get_public_ip(), 423)
server_socket.bind(server_address)
server_socket.listen(1)
connection, client_address = server_socket.accept()
print('connected to ', client_address)
while True:
    data = connection.recv(1024).decode()
    if not data:
        break
    print('received from the message:', data)
    message = input('content sent: ')
    connection.sendall(message.encode())
connection.close()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\main.py", line 11, in

server_socket.bind(server_address)

OSError: [WinError 10049] The requested address is invalid in this context

Comment: The address you bind to has to be the address that's assigned to the network interface. If you're behind a NAT router, you bind to the private IP in the Python code.

Comment: The way NAT works is that your computer thinks its private IP address is really its IP address, and the router does the translation. Therefore you have to tell it to bind to its private address (or all addresses) and let the router do the translation.

Comment: Just use `server_socket.bind(('', 423)`.  An empty string means "all available interfaces".  The *client* connects to the server IP.

Answer (score 0):

Listening directly on your public IP address will not work, as it's not a valid IP address in the context of your local network.

Instead, you should listen on [`0.0.0.0`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0). Using this address will make your server accessible on all interfaces and subnets connected to the machine running the server. Then, assuming you did correctly set up port-forwarding, firewalls and such, your server should be accessible using your public IP address from the world wide web.

Comment: the code works but I still can't connect because it looks like the query is not getting through at all and something is blocking it. And to be sure, I should have it set like this
DMZ enabled and set to 192.168.10.5 (my local IP)
firewall disabled
port forwarded from 423 to 423 to my IP address
What else could be causing it not to work?

Comment: And on the client I set a public IP

Comment: ISP says it doesn't block any ports

Comment: There are many possible places at which the request could be dropped. I don't think that you should use StackOverflow for debugging port-forwarding-related issues, and would instead ask a separate question on one of the other StackExchange sites.